# How to calculate days difference between two dates using struts2 tags in JSP

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have two dates in my JSP. I want to calculate days difference between the dates using Struts2 tags. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I did amount calculations  using struts2 tags but dates also is there , i am not getting

Comment: I do apologize, but I do not understand your comment.

Comment: sorry,In my  jsp page i am iterating list that contains date value .i want to compare that date with current date and that difference , i want to show

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your JSP and your controller?  Thank you.

Comment: Do the diff part inside your controller.

Comment: <s:iterator value="salesinvoicelist">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td><s:property value="SINo"/></td>
                                                    <td><s:date name="SIDate" format="dd/MM/yyyy"/></td></tr></s:iterator>

Comment: Don't post a code in comment, append it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSTL` tags like that :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

....

<fmt:parseNumber var="daysDifference"
                value="${( date1.time - date2.time ) / (1000*60*60*24) }" 
                integerOnly="true" />
```